# functional programming the first variable value?

Tags: javascript

```
(function() {

    var sample = "sample1";

    (function() {

        // set sample variable 
        sample = "sample2";

        (function() {

            // set sample variable
            sample = "sample3";
        }());
    }());



    console.log(sample); // "sample3"
}());
```

so; sample name @variable console.log results "sample3"; How do I get the first variable? "sample1" ??

```
console.log(sample); // --> "sample1" ??
```

thank You.

Comment: There's no 'first variable' here: there's only a single variable.

Comment: dynamic variable content, but ?? so sample @variable {{ name.tag }} ??

Comment: learn how scopes work... otherwise, you're wasting our time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare an independent `sample` variable in each scope:

```
(function() {

    var sample = "sample1";

    (function() {

        // set sample variable 
        var sample = "sample2";

        (function() {

            // set sample variable
           var sample = "sample3";
        }());
    }());

console.log(sample); // "sample1"
}());
```

[Try it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/nz9jZ/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Declare your variables instead of assigning to the outer one?

```
var sample = "sample2";
```

Also, *why*?

Answer (score 2):

An assignment *changes* the value that you have stored in a variable. It's not possible to get the old value back.

### Referencing variables

Whenever you reference a variable – read or write to it, that is – JavaScript will travel up the [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) [chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484143/scope-chain-in-javascript) until it finds a variable of that name, otherwise it will create it in the topmost scope: `window`, the global scope.

### Declaring variables

`var` declares a new variable in the current scope. If you were to prepend each assignment to `sample` with `var`, the variables would [shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373278/variable-shadowing-in-javascript) the outer ones. Why? Let's recall that JavaScript travels up the scope chain when you reference a variable. Obviously, it will find the ones in the nested scopes first, stopping it from looking further in parent scopes.

### What your code essentially does

Keeping in mind what happens when you reference a variable, we can transform your code to this, which is semantically equivalent (i.e. it is *exactly* what your code does):

```
var sample = "sample1";
sample = "sample2";
sample = "sample3";
console.log(sample);
```

Obviously, it's going to print `sample3` and you can't magically have an old value reappear.