# Update parent variable from within jQuery 'load'ed div

Tags: jquery, variables, load

I have a div that I load in with the jQuery 'load'. Is it possible to update a parent variable from within the loaded div?

i.e. parent var - `var testvar = 55`

and from with in the loaded div I set `testvar = 33`

now when the loaded div is closed, testvar is now = 33?

---

edit - example code: (I actually have two loads deep)

```
$(".bgBtn").click(function(){       
   $('#dialogLoad').show().load('../dialog/backgroundPicker.php');
})
```

inside the loaded #dialogLoad div:

```
var test = 44;

$(".newBgBtn").click(function(){        
   $('#bgs').load('../dialog/backgroundPicker2.php');
})
```

inside loaded #bgs div:

```
$(".button").click(function(){      
   test = 33;
})
```

Now the original var test is == 33

Comment: can you show what you have done?

Comment: Without the HTML it is difficult to say..

Comment: You need more to look at JS scoping... as your questions seems more related to scoping problems... start looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484143/scope-chain-in-javascript#1484230

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.parent()` in jquery. Find more [here](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) on jquery official site

UPDATE:

```
    $('#yourChildID').parent().val();
```

Comment: what is the syntax for using .parent() with a variable?