# javascript does not scope function parameter

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I wrote an array object and then wonna loop through the array. I am using underscore _.each function for do this work. Suddenly it happens unexpected thing in my code, consider the following code

```
var _ = require('underscore');

var myArray = [ 'RE', 'FR', 'TZ', 'SD'];

var traverse = function (element, index, list) {

    console.log(para1);
    console.log(element);

}

var func1 = function (para1) {
    _.each(myArray, traverse);
}

func1('test');
```

as output i have got the error message

```
Volumes/Develop/node_sample/scope.js:7
    console.log(para1);
                ^
ReferenceError: para1 is not defined
    at traverse (/Volumes/Develop/node_sample/scope.js:7:14)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Volumes/Develop/node_sample/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at func1 (/Volumes/Develop/node_sample/scope.js:13:4)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/Develop/node_sample/scope.js:16:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

Why the traverse function does not recognize para1 variable? I execute the _.each function in func and in my opinion should carry the scope with.
But if i write the code like this, then the scope chain works fine

```
var _ = require('underscore');

var myArray = [ 'RE', 'FR', 'TZ', 'SD'];

var func1 = function (para1) {
    _.each(myArray, function (element, index, list) {

        console.log(para1);
        console.log(element);

    });
}

func1('test');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've answered your own question. `para1` only exists within the scope of `func1`. You're not passing it to `traverse` in any way.

Your second example is fine, or you could do this instead:

```
var myArray = [ 'RE', 'FR', 'TZ', 'SD'];

var traverse = function (para1, myArray) {
  _.each(myArray, function (element, index, list) {
    console.log(para1);
    console.log(element);
  });
}

var func1 = function (para1) {
  traverse(para1, myArray);
}

func1('test');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LyUT4/7/).

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is not in the scope chain: [Scope Chain in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484143/scope-chain-in-javascript)

In the second example javascript is searching for 'para1' in the each method,
but there is no definition. After then the same search procedure will started with the parent function (close to func1) and at this there is a variable / argument called para1

I think you can pass para1 into the *.each method with help of context:
each*.each(list, iterator, [context])
I'm a jQuery guy so you have to check the docs on your own: http://underscorejs.org/#each

I hope it helps you

Cheers