# Passing variable as argument in closure

Tags: javascript, arguments, closures

I'm studying closures and found the following example code for incrementing a "private" variable named count:

```
function setup() {
    var count = 0;
    return function() {
        count += 1;
        console.log(count);
    }
 };
 var next = setup();
 next();
```

This makes sense to me. However, when I experimented with passing the variable as an argument to the nested function, next() logs 'NaN' to the console. Eg:

```
function setup() {
    var count = 0;
    return function(count) {
        count += 1;
        console.log(count);
    }
 };
 var next = setup();
 next();
```

Can someone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone explain why this happens?

Inside the closure, `count` now refers to the *parameter*, `function(count) {`. Since you are not passing any argument when you call the function, `count` is `undefined` and adding a number to `undefined` results in `NaN`.

> when I experimented with passing the variable as an argument to the nested function

**To be clear:** The `count` *parameter* has nothing to do with the `count` *variable* defined in the outer function. You are not passing the variable as argument, because you are not *calling* the function, you are *defining* it.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the inner function now has access to a more local variable, so it doesn't look at any closures it has access to for the "count" variable.  And nothing is passed, so count is undefined.

This answer may be useful: [Scope Chain in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484143/scope-chain-in-javascript)