# For loop function, unexpected output - always the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have this weird situation and I don't know why do the output is not what I expect. This is only a simple for-loop function. Can somebody explain me why this happens?

```
var pm = 2; 
for (var i = 0; i < pm; i++) {
     $("#specialty_pm_"+i).mouseenter(function(){
            alert(i);
    });
};
```

I have 2 divs in my html that has `id="specialty_pm_<?php echo $countPM; ?>"` and that div is inside a for loop function in php. `foreach ($employee_info as $emp_info){ $countPM++; }`
I expect that the alert on hover in the 1st div is '1' and the 2nd div is '2'. but when I hover the 1st div, it will alert '2'.

Comment: Have you checked the HTML to make sure each `id` is actually unique? Also post the HTML it produces.

Comment: and [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/218196)

Comment: and [Assign click handlers in for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4091765/218196)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason, as already mentioned, is that the scope of `i` is the same for both eventhandlers,  and as such it will have the same value for both of them.

There is a couple of solution for this problem.

Solution 1: create a new scope via a immediate function

```
var pm = 2; 
for (var i = 0; i < pm; i++) {
     $("#specialty_pm_"+i).mouseenter(function(instance){
        return function() {  alert(instance); };
    }(i));
};
```

You can see a fiddle of it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/LP6ZQ/

Solution 2: use jQuerys `data` method to store the value

```
var pm = 2; 
for (var i = 0; i < pm; i++) {
     $("#specialty_pm_"+i).data('instance',i).mouseenter(function(){
            alert($(this).data('instance'));
    });
};
```

You can see a fiddle of it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/LP6ZQ/1/

Solution 3: `bind` the instance number to the eventhandler

```
var pm = 2; 
for (var i = 0; i < pm; i++) {
     $("#specialty_pm_"+i).mouseenter(function(instance){
        alert(instance);
    }.bind(null,i));
};
```

You can see a fiddle of it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/LP6ZQ/2/

Solution 3 has a few caveats - `this` is being bound as `null`, and thus it can no longer be used as a reference to the dom element, like jQuery eventhandlers nomrally do. Also `bind` isn't supported by older browsers, but this can be mitigated by usinga  polyfill, a good one can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Solution 4: Be smart and use a delegate instead of binding event handlers in a loop

```
     $(document.body).on('mouseenter','.specialty_pm',function(){
        alert($(this).data('id'));
    });
```

You can see a fiddle of it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/LP6ZQ/4/

Solution 4 is the "right way" to do it, but it will require you to change the way you build your markup

Answer (score 3):

you should use JavaScript closure:

```
var pm = 2; 
for (var i = 0; i < pm; i++) {
    var func = (function(i){
        return function(){
            alert(i);
        }
    })(i);
    $("#specialty_pm_"+i).mouseenter(func);
};
```

The point is in your code all the mouseenter functions use the same variable `i`, and after your loop ends, it has its last value which is `2`. Using a scope chain, with nested functions and their closures in JavaScript, you can create safe scopes for your variables. Basically what nested functions do, is to provide a outer LexicalEnvironment for the inner function. You can find more information in this post:

[Scope Chain in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484143/scope-chain-in-javascript).

Comment: *"Using closures in JavaScript you can create safe scopes for your variables."* No no no! The way closures work in JS is the **reason** for this problem in the first place. The event handlers that are created in the loop are *already* closures. Closures themselves don't create scope, only *function invocation* creates a new scope. And that's the solution to the problem: Execute a function to create a new scope. Whether that function is a closure or not doesn't matter.

Comment: @FelixKling: My bad in describing the whole concept and thanks for your informative feedback. I try to be more descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

You alert can't wirks because `i` has only one instance.
Yoi can check variable i inside your div in this case.

try this:

```
$("#specialty_pm_"+i).mouseenter(function(){
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     alert(id.substring(0,13));
});
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? Care to provide an explanation?

Comment: yes the instance is only one of that variable @user2864740

Answer (score 0):

You could get rid of the `for` loop in your JavaScript and use [jQuery's Starts With Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to select ALL elements whose `id` begins with `'specialty_pm_'`

```
$("[id^='specialty_pm_']").on("mouseenter",function(){
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     alert(id.substring(13));
});
```

E.G: http://jsfiddle.net/6bTJ3/

Alternatively you could add a `class` to each of these `specialty_pm_[n]` items to make it even simpler to select them in jQuery.