# Laravel Eloquent with not identifying variables

Tags: php, closures

I am trying to use laravel-eloquent to get the rooms and their bookings which are after a particular date.

```
$fdate='2015-01-05';
$roomdata=Rooms::where('city_id','=',$citydata['id'])
->with('types')
->with('localities')
->with('slideshow')
->with(array('booking' => function($query){
    $query->where('bookstart','>',$fdate);
}))
->get();
```

This is giving me an error saying `$fdate` is undefined. But when I do

```
$query->where('bookstart','>','2015-01-05');
```

This works great. Any reason behind this? Can someone provide a good solution for this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using a [closure](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) inside of the callback to `with`.  First, a quote from that doc page:

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be passed to the use language construct.

You are attempting to access a variable from the parent scope inside your anonymous function, so you must first pass it to the `use` construct in order to let PHP know you are creating the closure around that variable:

```
$roomdata = Rooms::where('city_id','=',$citydata['id'])
    ->with('types')
    ->with('localities')
    ->with('slideshow')
    ->with(array('booking' => function($query) use($fdate) {
        $query->where('bookstart','>',$fdate);
    }))
;
```

Contrast this with Javascript, which allows a programmer to automatically access the parent scope because each child scope is part of the parent scope's [Scope Chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484143/scope-chain-in-javascript).  Something like this would be valid in Javascript:

```
var foo = 'bar';
(function() {
    alert(foo);
})();
```

In PHP, gaining access to outer variables from within inner functions is not automatic.  In this way, PHP differentiates between [*closures* and *anonymous functions*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220658/what-is-the-difference-between-a-closure-and-a-lambda) (aka 'lambdas') in a way that JavaScript does not, at least syntax-wise.  However, this is not clearly spelt out in the documentation (the manual seems to equate the two, when they're really not the same).

Answer (score 1):

Variable scope:

```
    $fdate='2015-01-05';
    $roomdata=Rooms::where('city_id','=',$citydata['id'])
    ->with('types')
    ->with('localities')
    ->with('slideshow')
    ->with(array('booking' => function($query) use ($fdate){
        $query->where('bookstart','>',$fdate);
    }))
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

put semicolon like so:

```
$fdate='2015-01-05';
```

Comment: I do have sorry my bad i missed it while copying my code