# Function in my button wont reload another function

Tags: javascript, function

I want the "Continue Playing" button to reload the game but keep the score. After I click the button it keeps the score but doesn't give me the correct answer after I click the shape.  What am I missing here?  Below is my code, you can also view it in jsFiddle to see it in action.

```
var shapeName = ["Square", "Rectangle"];
var score = 0;

var cssIdSquare = "<div id='square' onclick='sqrClick()'></div>";
var cssIdRec = "<div id='rect'onclick='rectClick()' ></div>";

var docMyAnswer = document.getElementById("myAnswer");
var docMyScore = document.getElementById("score");

var answerCorrect = "CORRECT!";
var answerWrong = "WRONG!";

// Random Shape to Select Title

var shapesTitle = shapeName[Math.floor(Math.random() * shapeName.length)];
document.getElementById("IdShapeTitle").innerHTML = shapesTitle.toString();

///// Function Shape Logic

function showAllShapes() {

    ///// Show both shapes
    document.getElementById("showShapes").innerHTML = cssIdSquare + "<br>" + cssIdRec;
}

function sqrClick() {
    if (shapesTitle === "Square") {
        docMyAnswer.innerHTML = answerCorrect;
        score += 1;
        docMyScore.innerHTML = score;
    }
    if (shapesTitle === "Rectangle") {
        docMyAnswer.innerHTML = answerWrong;
    }
}

function rectClick() {
    if (shapesTitle === "Rectangle") {
        docMyAnswer.innerHTML = answerCorrect;
        score += 1;
        docMyScore.innerHTML = score;
    }
    if (shapesTitle === "Square") {
        docMyAnswer = answerWrong;
    }
}

showAllShapes();


// Continue Playing Button
function btnContPlay() {
var shapesTitle = shapeName[Math.floor(Math.random() * shapeName.length)];
document.getElementById("IdShapeTitle").innerHTML = shapesTitle.toString();
showAllShapes();

}



// Start Over Button
function btnStartOver() {
    score = 0; // reset score to 0
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
    location.reload();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/arevee/39rgqevy/

*** Also if you have any tips on shortening the code, I would like to hear. Also I would like to keep this using functions, my next project will be learning about objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is in `shapeTitle variable`.Inside `btnContPlay()` function you have a new `shapeTitle` variable because you have started with it with `var` keyword.Your `sqarClick` and `rectClick` functions don't have access to this newly created variable.***Remember in javascript functions create their own scope***.Your first `shapeTitle` variable was on ***global scope***.

your `btnContPlay()` function is:

```
function btnContPlay() {
var shapesTitle = shapeName[Math.floor(Math.random() * shapeName.length)];
document.getElementById("IdShapeTitle").innerHTML = shapesTitle.toString();
showAllShapes();

}
```

change it to

```
   function btnContPlay() {
     shapesTitle = shapeName[Math.floor(Math.random() *shapeName.length)]; //removed var from shapesTitle
    document.getElementById("IdShapeTitle").innerHTML = shapesTitle.toString();
    showAllShapes();

    }
```

So without `var` keyword ,it will not create a new variable inside function's scope,and now  it will effect the global `shapeTitle` variable.This is a [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484143/scope-chain-in-javascript) related problem.Removing it will solve your problem. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39rgqevy/15/)