# JavaScript constructor: is this a property or a variable?

Tags: javascript

I was surfing on the canvas element, to use with JavaScript games and I found this code:

```
function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    ctx = myGameArea.context; // **why not: var ctx= myGameArea.context ???**
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}
```

My question is what is `ctx` a property? Or a private variable?

`ctx` is not declared or even used, outside of this constructor (like: `var ctx`). It is only inside this code.

I hear if you set a variable with a value directly without the `var` reserved word, you are declaring a global. But that `ctx` variable is not being used outside that constructor, so is useless?

Also they do the same thing when setting the `key` property to an instance of an object.

The entirely code...

```
var myGamePiece;

function startGame() {
    myGameArea.start();
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    ctx = myGameArea.context;
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}
```

Comment: actually it is a global variable.

Comment: Yes, looks like bad code. It should most likely be `var ctx`.

Comment: It's a variable, but it could be declared outside of that function, so it's not necessarily global.

Comment: Yup.. It should be `var ctx` to get the context of the canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it seems that it is a pretty  bad practice not to declare it at least as var. If a variable is not declared with var/let/const, the Javascript engine will define them in the global namespace and can have unknown side effects. It is a bit worrying that there is an access to the `myGameArea` global (?) variable. Why is this not injected into the constructor? Something like that would have been clearer:

```
function component(width, height, color, x, y, myGameArea) {
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;

  var ctx = myGameArea.context;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}
```

Comment: I think ctx should be a private variable 'var', since it purpouse is for a final thing.

Comment: @vincentthorpe If you need it private then definitely should be defined as var. Just did the change.

Answer (score 1):

If that function is by itself and not inside another function then chances are `ctx` is a global variable. If a local variable is desired `var ctx` should be used instead, but will not be accessible from the outside. If access to the `ctx` variable is desired then it it should be declared as `this.ctx`.

If it is inside another function then it could be a captured variable:

```
function parent() {
    var ctx = parentArea.context;

    function component(width, height color, x, y) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        ctx = myGameArea.context; // References parent's ctx variable
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to a variable inside the body of a function, JS will search the [scope chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484143/scope-chain-in-javascript) of the function to find the variable.

If the variable was not declared inside the function itself, then it will look in the scope of any enclosing function(s), then finally in the global scope.

From the fragment you presented we can't see if ctx is declared in an enclosing function, or is a global variable, although you say it is not used outside the constructor which implies it is not declared anywhere. On balance I would say it the author accidentally used a global instead of a local variable.

As an aside: I recommend using a tool such as [jshint](http://jshint.com/) to pick up errors such as using global variables by mistake.